# How to increase the size of android window title

Tags: android

I need to increase the length of the window title image of my activity.I used the attribute `android:windowTitleSize` but while using this the whole size of the image is increasing, but i need to increase only the length of the title image.

please help me!

Comment: Improve your accept ratio first.Then only someone will be interested in helping you!

Answer (score 0):

do with Java code -- those android:windowTitleSize are for app init